# excel: generate missing years in year range either in VBA or function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, range, vba

I've been searching for hours for a function / vba macro solution to my problem -  unfortunately to no avail... Maybe you guys can help?

I need to generate the 'gap' years within a range (year_start <-> year_end - separate inputs) i.e. for 1997-2002, the script should generate (preferable in one column, with values separated by ,) the following: 1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002.

Please help!

Your help is greatly appreciated in advance!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you must use VBA, instead of Excel's built in **Autofill**, try something like this:

```
dim iYear As Integer, iYearS as integer, iYearE as integer, iOffset as integer
dim oRangeStart as range

set orangestart=range("A1")

iYearS =1997
iYearE = 2002

for iYear = iYearS to iYearE
    orangestart.offset(iOffset,0).value=iyear
    iOffset=iOffset+1
next
```

but you could just Autofill surely?

Comment: Thank you - I'll try your script. Can't use Autofill as this has to happen on a 'case-by-case / row-by-row' basis automatically

Comment: Can we update the script to generate the dates based on dynamic values? I.e. Content from Column A -> year_start and Column B-> year end. It should then generate the results in the corresponding cell of say, Column C

Comment: How do I get the results into one cell? i.e. result entries split up with commas in one cell? -- Please help!

Comment: @user2381937: inside the loop, you would remove the line `iOffset=...` to stop it from incrementing, and edit the line putting in the values to concatenate the values like `orangestart.value = orangestart.value & ", "`